# Anyone help me write a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Data from table users

[image]

As you can see there are `id` and `added_by_id` columns, I want to fetch all the users added by a specific id but if the id in that result has also added someone then I should get that also.

Example:- if I want to find all the IDs added by 1 then I should get 2,3,4,5,6,7. Now if you are thinking why 4, that's, because 4 was added by 2, and 2, was added by 1.

And if I want to find all the IDs added by 2 then I should get 4 and other IDs added by 4 and other IDs added by Other IDs....I hope you got my point.

They can only see below not above in the hierarchy.

Can anyone help me write this complex query?

Want to get kind of recurring details...I don't know if I explained it correctly.

Comment: Please add sample data, the query you have tried, the output you get and the expected output as text to your question

Comment: sample data in the image

Comment: Do not post data as images or to external links. The question should be self-contained. Also SO is not a coding/query writting service. We expect you've tried somethig and show that attemp

Comment: If i get your question very well, you are trying to fetch that was added by user_id: `added_by_id`? I think this is simple, what i've you tried? or are you new to `sql`?

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is query that I've tried. I Hop this will help you.

```
SELECT id FROM(
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS ( SELECT *
         FROM tb_user
         WHERE id = 1
       UNION ALL
         SELECT tb_user.*
         FROM cte
         JOIN TBL1 ON  tb_user.id =cte.added_by_id )
SELECT id , added_by_id 
FROM cte ) as T WHERE T.added_by_id IS NOT NULL AND parent!=1
```

Comment: Hi i really hope ur answer is correct but can u change few thing and kindly explain it.
the table name where my data is stored is called "tb_user", could u please use this info in ur answer and what is parent,cte,TBL1 in ur answer.

Comment: @PriyanshKhandelwal I've updated table name,as you needed.

Comment: @PriyanshKhandelwal you can check for [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

Comment: thanks alot @ Hiren Patel though your answer didn't give the result i wanted but i got the hint and wrote a solution:-
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy 
AS (
SELECT id, added_by_id 
FROM tb_user
WHERE added_by_id = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT e.id, e.added_by_id
FROM tb_user e, hierarchy
WHERE e.added_by_id = hierarchy.id )
SELECT * FROM hierarchy;

Answer (score -1):

I think you can add another column, called `first_level_id`, you put the highest parent user_id that you can get when inserting new rows, and probably refresh all the existing rows for the value stored in first_level_id, and after that, you can get what you want with

```
select id from xxx where first_level_id = 1;
```